# PLSQL - Return a collection of codes

Tags: plsql

I am trying to write a function to return a list of code.

In the package spec I have declared

```
type codes_t is table of number;
```

and

```
function getCodes(
   acc_id in Account.id%type
)
return codes_t;
```

In the body I have

```
function getCodes(
  acc_id in Account.id%type
)
return codes_t
is
  v_codes codes_t := codes_t();
begin
   for row in (select ...) loop
     v_codes.extend();
     v_codes(v_codes.count) := row.code;
   end loop;
return codes_t;
```

The package compilers without errors but when I try to call the function with

```
select pkg.getCodes(123) from dual;
```

I get *ORA-00902: Invalid datatype*

Anything obviously wrong?

Comment: "Invalid datatype" at line?

Comment: @hotfix I've updated the question. The line in the error doesn't refer to the function itself but to the call to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to call the function in SQL, and it returns an array, you need to do two things:

1. Create the type as a database type (i.e. `create type ...`) so that the SQL engine can know about the datatype
2. cast the function's output to a table and select from that, e.g. `select * from table(<function>)`

Doing those two things should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks. I actually use the _select_ just to test the function in SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Or it can be pipelined.
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b819154d2659cb433aecd9d52dc0fa1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg
is

type codes_t is table of number;

function getCodes(
   acc_id in NUMBER
)
return codes_t PIPELINED;
end pkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
is
  function getCodes(
    acc_id in NUMBER
  ) return codes_t PIPELINED
  is
    v_codes codes_t := codes_t();
  begin
     for r in (select acc_id as code from dual
                union 
                 select acc_id+1 from dual) loop
              PIPE row(r.code);
     end loop;
  end getCodes;
end pkg;
/
```